# UIAlertView does not work with UIBarButton

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a strange problem:
Trying to call an action which contains `NSLog` and `UIAlert` using a `UIBarButtonItem` from a `NavigationController`. **NSLog prints** and `UIAlert` doesn't appear…

```
-(void)addNewItem
{
    UIAlertView *alertAddnewItem = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hello!" message:@"hello!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
    [self.view addSubview:alertAddnewItem];

    NSLog(@"Hello!");
}
```

I guess the problems is with `[self.view addSubview:alertAddnewItem];`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call:

```
[alertAddnewItem show];
```

not

```
[self.view addSubview:alertAddnewItem];
```